# Windows form hot keys using ALT+Key, if the same key combination with case change

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

We have created windows form which has two buttons Cancel and clear.
we have give button text as &Cancel and &clear for shortcut key combination as <kbd>Alt+key</kbd>.
but when we press <kbd>Alt+c</kbd> it only works for cancel button.
Instead why it won't tab between these two buttons in Windows form, which works like tabbing in VB6 forms.
I need to tab between these two buttons if <kbd>Alt+c</kbd> is pressed.
Please suggest any form property or button property needs to be set to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the ProcessCmdKey method. The below should work if you press alt, let go of alt, and then press the *c* key.

```
private bool altPressed;
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (altPressed)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.C)
            {
                this.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
                altPressed = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (keyData == (Keys.Menu | Keys.Alt))
        {
            altPressed = true;
            return true;
        }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```